# [__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 517431040 beyond bounds [0 .. 48]

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I fond this error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936760/nsarraym-objectatindex-index-4294967295-beyond-bounds-for-empty-array-wit), but it came to the conclusion that the error occurs because the array is empty. My array however is not empty.

```
-(void)setNumberInTippfield:(NSNumber *)aNumber{
  NSNumber *index = [self.ticket.currentSlip intValue]-1;
  NSLog(@"index: %i",index);//prints 0, expected
  Slip *slip = [self.slipArray objectAtIndex:index];
  NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[aNumber intValue]-1 ];
  NSLog(@"number: %@",number);//prints out number, e.g. 25, as expected
  NSMutableArray *tNumberArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  tNumberArray= [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:slip.numberArray];
  //after this line, debugger tells me the array has 49 objects, as expected
  [[tNumberArray objectAtIndex:number] setSelected:YES];//this line throws exception
  //this line seems to get executed 3 times, as I can see from the breakpoints
}
```

after that it throws an exception:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -
[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 517431040 beyond bounds [0 .. 48]'
```

I thought that `number` holds an adress instead of a value, but NSLog tells me the correct value. Any hints on that one? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Which call to `objectAtIndex` is throwing this exception?

Comment: the last line, see my edit.

Comment: Because NSLog prints the value of [object description], not the object itself.

Comment: so many "how to do dat, show me code" questions on stackoverflow, and I get the downvote...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`objectAtIndex:` takes an `int`, not a `NSNumber`.

```
// ...
Slip *slip = [self.slipArray objectAtIndex:[index intValue]];
```

Edit:

The following line raises a question, too:

```
NSNumber *index = [self.ticket.currentSlip intValue]-1;
```

Shouldn't the result be an `int`? That would fix the problems that follow.

Comment: Same goes for the second instance of `objectAtIndex:`

Comment: super! it works, thank you! The first instance of it works however, strange.

Comment: @dan - it's not "strange", you've assigned an `int` value (`[self.ticket.currentSlip intValue]-1`0 to a pointer - which is legal in C. You then pass that pointer as an integer `[self.slipArray objectAtIndex:index]`, again legal, and it all works. You need to make sure you understand the difference between a primitive value type, such as `int`, and an object that represents a value, such as `NSNumber` - the two are not interchangeable. (Maybe you are used to C# where (un)boxing is automatic?)

Comment: I understand, though Im lacking of this in-depth knowledge, or dont think about it too much. Thanks a lot for the information.